# Should I unit-test all possible inputs in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I have a method with with the following signature:

```
ConfigTreeNode FilterFirstChild<T>(Func<ConfigTreeNode, T> getProp, T key)
```

The usage is as follows:

```
MyObj.FilterFirstChild(x => x.Prop1, "foo") //assuiming Prop1 is a string
```

The caller can use any property in place of `Prop1` (i.e `Prop2`, `Prop3`).

Now my question is should I be writing multiple unit tests covering all possible properties?

i.e

```
public void FilterFirstChild_GivenChildProp1_ReturnsCorrectChild()
public void FilterFirstChild_GivenChildProp2_ReturnsCorrectChild()
public void FilterFirstChild_GivenChildProp3_ReturnsCorrectChild()
```

Or should I just write one test that tests the general working behaviour

i.e

```
public void FilterFirstChild_GivenChildProp_ReturnsCorrectChild() // not prop1, prop2... etc
```

Apologies if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally unit tests' aim is to cover scenarios (i.e. if-conditions), not all possible data inputs. If there is any difference between processing `Prop1` from `Prop2`, so it make sense to cover both. If not - leaving generic test is okay.

Also it's worth mentioning that unit tests frameworks usually have a tool to run tests against multiple set of data. For example `NUnit` has `TestCaseAttribute`:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(SomeEnum.SomeValue)]
public void MethodName_Condition_ThrowsException(SomeEnum someValue)
{
//...
}
```